# Better way to check for a Int in a textbox

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Xcode and creating a very simply program with a textbox(txt box) in which the user enters a value, a button (btnCalc) that performs a calculation, and a label (lblcalcdnumber) that shows the calc'd number.  I have already selected Number Pad to be displayed as the dropdown keyboard but i want to check to make sure that if they enter anything other than a number that nothing happens.  The code i have works but i feel like there should be a cleaner solution.  Essential i want them to only enter Integers in the textbook.

```
    // Mark: Actions
@IBAction func btnCalc(sender: UIButton) {

        // let txtbox text beome int
    let number1 = Int(txtBox.text!)
        // let possibleInt convert mystring to int to check for nil, txtbox becomes OPTIONAL
    let possibleInt = Int(txtBox.text!)
    let number = 25

    if possibleInt != nil {
        let combinednumber = "\(Int(number1!) * number)"
        lblCalcedNumber.text = combinednumber
    }
    else {
        txtBox.text = ""
        txtBox.placeholder = "Please Enter a Valid Number"

    }

}
```

Comment: Kind of broad. Do you not know how to know whether it's a number? Do you want suggestions on a better interface for validation? What?

Comment: I am looking for am easier way to validate.  I am very beginner and just felt that my code was very "clunky".  cfatt10 already has helped to clean it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if and let together to create an optional. If the value is not nil it will cast to possibleInt, otherwise, it will evaluate as false.

```
@IBAction func btnCalc(sender: UIButton) {

    if let possibleInt = Int(txtBox.text!) {
        let combinednumber = "\(possibleInt * 25)"
        lblCalcedNumber.text = combinednumber
    }
    else {
        txtBox.text = ""
        txtBox.placeholder = "Please Enter a Valid Number"
    }
}
```

Comment: What i have learned is that i was on the correct track and i appreciate the help.  I selected Will Park as it uses the cleanest option.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables 'number1' and 'possibleInt' have the same value, so you only need one of them for this section of code. Since 'number' is only used once it would be better to use the value itself rather than create a variable for it, however, if you use it elsewhere keep it as a variable so you only need to change your code in one spot. If you weren't using the possibleInt/number1 value inside the if statement, you could be even more efficient by doing `if Int(txtBox.text!) != nil`. Try this:

```
    // Mark: Actions
@IBAction func btnCalc(sender: UIButton) {

    let possibleInt = Int(txtBox.text!)

    if possibleInt != nil {
        let combinednumber = "\(possibleInt * 25)"
        lblCalcedNumber.text = combinednumber
    }
    else {
        txtBox.text = ""
        txtBox.placeholder = "Please Enter a Valid Number"
    }
}
```

Comment: That already helps me to clean it up a lot.  i thought that i needed to use a variable to make it Optional.  When i use your code i get an error the the line "let combined number = "\(possibleInt * 25)" is not wrapped.  this is why i added the two different variables with the same value

Comment: Is it possible you forgot the backslash?